# Question for the derivation of the probability of a trajectory

Tags: probability, reinforcement-learning

I'm studying reinforcement learning now and I'm quite a newbie to this field.

I have some questions about how to derive the equation as below.

$p_{\theta}(s_{1},a_{1},\dots,s_T,a_T)=p(s_1)\prod_{t=1}^T(\pi_\theta(a_t|s_t)p(s_{t+1}|s_t,a_t))$

The equation above is the probability of a trajectory.

But in my opinion, the equation should be,
$p_{\theta}(s_{1},a_{1},\dots,s_T,a_T)=p(s_1)\prod_{t=1}^T\pi_\theta(a_t|s_t)\prod_{t=1}^{T-1}p(s_{t+1}|s_t,a_t)$

I don't know why $p(s_{T+1}|s_T,a_T)$ emerges in the original equation because there is no $s_{T+1},a_{T+1}$ in the trajectory. I think I'm missing something.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about reinforcement learning, but start with an easy case and repeatedly apply the law $p(x,y|z) = p(x|z)p(y|x,z)$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
p(a_1,a_2,s_1,s_2) &= p(s_1)p(a_2,a_1,s_2|s_1)\\
&= p(s_1)p(a_1|s_1)p(a_2,s_2|a_1,s_1)\\
&= p(s_1)p(a_1|s_1)p(s_2|a_1,s_1)p(a_2|a_1,s_1,s_2)\\
&= p(s_1)p(a_1|s_1)p(a_2|s_2)p(s_2|a_1,s_1)\\
\end{aligned}
$$

(assuming actions depend only on the last state) which agrees with your second equation. The first equation you gave must be incorrect because the RHS has terms involving $s_{T+1}$ (and the LHS does not contain an $s_{T+1}$).

Your second equation looks like it's probably correct to me

Comment: Thank you! I agree with your answer, but many texts or lecture notes still just use the first equation. That's why I'm still suspicious about the second equation.